# Uncaught Duplicate entry error. But its not a duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

This is the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Duplicate entry '8-1' for key 'PRIMARY'<br /><br /> thrown in prestashop/classes/db/Db.php on line 613
```

The Database:

```
Column  Type    Comment
id_category int(10) unsigned     
id_group    int(10) unsigned    

Indexes
PRIMARY id_category, id_group
INDEX   id_category
INDEX   id_group
```

The thing is I am sure there isn't any duplicate 8,1 entry in the table.
There is 7,1 7,2 7,3 , but no 8,1 in the table. The var_dump in the previous line is only shown once so its not being called twice.
I just don't get it .
All I had done was manually truncate a few prestashop tables(using a custom tool), after which these errors have been coming. Now I ran the prestashop cleaner, but still getting this error.

Edit The sql insert statement:

```
>INSERT INTO `ps_category_group` (`id_category`, `id_group`) VALUES ('8', '1'), ('8', '2'), ('8', '3')
```

Comment: Can you show some example data?

Comment: Thats the thing, its giving the error even with an empty table. Is there a possiblity that the indexes weren't deleted, when the table was truncated..

Comment: Truncate internally does a drop, create command. So there's little chance of an index being preserved. I've never seen an incorrect "Duplicate Key" error

Comment: You could try dropping the entire database and backing it up.

Comment: I think I'll have to a db drop only.

Comment: Also, I see you've created duplicate indexes. You have a PK composite index on category and group, then you also have an index on category, and an index on group. The id_category index won't ever be used. The id_group index will ever be used if your query isn't using the id_category index. Read up on [composite indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Comment: Thanks Mike. I think I found the error. Its quite embarassing, array instead of string.